# Codeigniter linking pages to each other

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

This may be a bit confusing to you but I'll try to make it as simple as possible.

I am working on a simple project where I have only one type of content coming from my database. When a user lands on my website they will be seeing one of random entries as home page view and then they will be able to click on next and previous to see other available pages.

It may work like pagination, but the difference is that pagination pulls all entries from database and lists them based on number of listing per page. My approach is the exact article page to have only next article and previous article links on every page.

Would you please let me know how would you approach this if it was your application? I'm looking forward to hearing your thoughts.

Thank you.

Comment: did you try anything ?

Comment: no im asking for approaches not actual code - I do django and python and its way different from php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to build a query which returns max three rows - one for prev data, one for current data and another one for next data.

Now you have to check if prev data not found in the query result then do not show prev link in the page

Also you have to check if next data not found in the query result then do not show next link in the page.

Query for first page will return two rows and for next page onwards will return three rows. for last page query will return two rows.

Depending on the which links getting clicked you have to build the query.

For first page you return the query with first and next records from the db. from next page onwards you have to get the clicked link's id and determine the prev and next data for next page onwards.